# For loop calculates the Celsius equivalent to Fahrenheit Temperatures Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with this program. I get no compile errors, but when I run it didn’t display the decimal point for Celsius output.

Here is my code:

```
public class TempLoops {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int fahrenheit = 0;

        System.out.println("Fahrenheit    Celsius");

        for ( fahrenheit = 0; fahrenheit <= 300; fahrenheit+= 20) {    

            System.out.printf("%5d        ",fahrenheit);
            double Celsius = (fahrenheit-32.0) * (5.0/9.0);  // formula for celsius to fahrenheit conversion

            System.out.printf("%5d", (int)Celsius );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get digits behind the decimal point for Celsius output?

Here is the sample output for what it suppose to look like
[sample out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCbut.jpg)

Comment: Don't cast `Celsius` to an `int`?

Comment: Don't print celsius using an integer format specifier?

Comment: As stated by @GriffeyDog don't place `(int)` before `Celcius`, but also please follow Java naming conventions: `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT` this way it will be easier for you and us to read your program

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
System.out.printf("%5d", (int)Celsius );
```

to this

```
System.out.printf("%0.2f", Celsius );
```

This will print centigrades with 2 decimal places.

The main reason why you are getting integer output is because you are casting float(ing point number like x.abcd) into integer number, cutting of what is left as fracture part (resulting in x alone).

Comment: getting error when I put %0.2f: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %0.2f at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkNumeric(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

**Use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) to solve your problem.**

**Working Code :**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TempLoops {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");  // this will helps you to always keeps in two decimal places

        int fahrenheit = 0;

        System.out.println("Fahrenheit    Celsius");

        for ( fahrenheit = 0; fahrenheit <= 300; fahrenheit+= 20) {    

            System.out.printf("   "+fahrenheit);
            double Celsius = (fahrenheit-32.0) * (5.0/9.0);  // formula for celsius to fahrenheit conversion

            System.out.printf("\t\t"+f.format(Celsius));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Kindly refer to** [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) **for more information about** [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)